# How to handle every link click on a page in JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

People create their own websites using WYSIWYG creator i give them. These websites have links inside of them. Also they can explore the HTML of the website and put there their own links.

I would like now to handle every link click occurring in website created with my creator and log it to my server. I know how to pass the data from JS or jQuery to PHP server. But what i need to know is how to handle the moment when person clicks a link, postpone the redirection for some moment, and in this time get the url and title of this link and send to my PHP server.

So how to handle every link click (or location change) on website that structure i don't know and get the link and title of the link clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');

    // Send your data to php
    if ($(this).attr('target') === '_blank') {
        window.location.href = href;  // redirect to href
    } else {
        window.open(href);
    }
});
```

Comment: hello and how to redirect to href?

Comment: And further more how to simulate the links with target="_blank" for example?

Comment: it looks nice. One tiny bug: attr('title')- should be target not?

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. I found that I also had to wrap the `.click` handler in `$(document).ready` to make sure the DOM is available before attaching the handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17663761/550712.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("a").click(function(){  
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $.post('/', {link: href}).then(function(){ document.location = href; });
  return false;
});
```

just a try

Comment: and what the '/', {link: href} does?

Comment: I think he was just showing that you should place your ajax call there. Since he doesn't know your specifics he placed those values in.

Answer (score 1):

To intercept every link, just place this function somewhere that every page has access to (header/footer/etc.):

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();//To prevent following the link

    //Your logic. attr('href') and attr('title')
});
```

Comment: ...i don't want to call click event. I want to handle click events.

Comment: @Grails And how to handle all clicks on the website and how to postpone redirect?

Comment: @Teemu The second comment is grails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this. Use the `on` event and bind to the click event of `a` element. You can then do an `event.preventDefault();` do your logic and then continue as normal by getting the `href` from the target.

Comment: what on event? how to get the url and title? how to postpone redirect?

Comment: take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/on/ (the url and title can be obtained from the params passed into the event and event.preventDefault() will postpone the redirect)

Comment: +Magrangs The website you pasted didnt work. It works now. So on is to bind to event. Ok. What next?

Comment: Firstly, you need to read the documentation about 'on'. Go to the jquery website and read that. (p.s. try adding http:// to my link, the link works for me fine so not sure why you are having issues)

Comment: +Magrangs it works for me now. it didnt work before. Sorry but if i wanted to research everything the whole point of SO would not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to wait till logging is completed for the redirection. Let it be an asynchronous call so that user don't need to wait. If you want to have your server page in a different domain, to tackle the cross domain ajax issue, use jsonp datatype.

```
$('a').click(function() {

   $.ajax({
     url:"yourwebsite/loggingpage.php?data="+$(this).attr("href"),
     dataType: 'jsonp' // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)         

  });

});
```

and in loggingpage.php, you can read the request data and log it to your persistent storage or wherever you want.