# event.preventDefault(); not working

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a form without refreshing the page, but `event.preventDefault();` isn't working. Here's what I have thus far

```
$('#contactform').on('submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};
        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();
            data[name] = value;
        });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        succss: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

But the page still re-loads once the submit button has been pressed. Any suggestions?

Update: The code for the main form page is as follows;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/ajax/main.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax/contact.php" method="post" id="contactform">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `return false` at the end of your `on submit` function?

Comment: @jterry that's bad practice. You should be using `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the action from occurring. nullability has the correct solution.

Comment: How is it not working? Is event.preventDefault() even executed in your case?

Answer (score 12):

You need to pass the event to the function as the first parameter.

```
$('#contactform').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

...
```

If that doesn't work, you may have an additional problem. You need to make sure the DOM is ready before binding anything to the form by wrapping your listener in a `.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactform').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
```

Comment: Hmmm still no luck. Here is the main contact form code is it helps `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/ajax/main.js"></script>` and `<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax/contact.php" method="post" id="contactform"><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name" /><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" /></form>`

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information about DOM readiness.

Comment: Hmmm no dice with that either :(

Comment: The only other idea I have is to rename `event` to something else like `e` in case something else is defining it. I know IE has a global `event` variable...

Comment: The tip on making the DOM ready got my code working. Thank you!

Comment: Gosh... $(document).ready(function() solved my problem. Thanks @nullability

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `event` into the function call:

```
$('#contactform').on('submit', function(event) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
 });
```